# Moving files using ecma script in ribbon custom action

Tags: 2010, javascript

I found this nice article about copying files from one location to another FIXED location.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/05/28/sharepoint-2010-ecmascript-copymove-files-to-another-document-library-part-2/

However this copies but not moves, I can't find any documentation about moving files using ecmascript, but I suppose it should be possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line of code - `File.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, true);`

to

```
File.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl, true);
```

It should work.

Comment: You should be using the enum from the answer below:
`File.MoveTo(_destinationLibUrl, SP.MoveOperations.none);`

Answer (score 3):

You need to set operation flag instead of boolean variable as the second parameter. For example

```
File.MoveTo(_destinationLibUrl, SP.MoveOperations.none);
```

here's a link to a full list of possible operations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556657.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl,1);
```

This is what got it working for me

Comment: Please provide more information.